# Running jhipster application in production profile

Tags: webpack, jhipster, yarnpkg

I am trying to start jhipster spring boot and angular 4 application in production mode using command './mvnw -Pprod' ,but it gives me error shown in stacktrace

....

```
 yarn install v1.3.2
[INFO] [1/5] Validating package.json...
[INFO] [2/5] Resolving packages...
[INFO] [3/5] Fetching packages...
[INFO] info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
[INFO] info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[INFO] [4/5] Linking dependencies...
[ERROR] warning "@angular/cli > @schematics/angular@0.0.49" has incorrect peer dependency "@angular-devkit/schematics@0.0.34".
[ERROR] warning "@angular/cli > license-webpack-plugin@1.1.1" has unmet peer dependency "webpack-sources@>=1.0.0".

[INFO] [5/5] Rebuilding all packages...
[INFO] success Saved lockfile.
[INFO] $ node node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/install.js
[INFO] Found PhantomJS at C:\Vidyashree2016\jBPMDevelopment\los_prod_cp\LoanOriginatingSystem\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe ...verifying
[INFO] PhantomJS is previously installed at C:\Vidyashree2016\jBPMDevelopment\los_prod_cp\LoanOriginatingSystem\node_modules\phantomjs-prebuilt\lib\phantom\bin\phantomjs.exe
[INFO] Done in 421.19s.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.2:yarn (webpack build prod) @ pods ---
[INFO] Running 'yarn run webpack:prod' in C:\Vidyashree2016\jBPMDevelopment\los_prod_cp\LoanOriginatingSystem
[INFO] yarn run v1.3.2
[INFO] $ yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:prod:main && yarn run clean-www
[INFO] $ rimraf target/{aot,www}
[INFO] $ yarn run webpack -- --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile
[ERROR] warning From Yarn 1.0 onwards, scripts don't require "--" for options to be forwarded. In a future version, any explicit "--" will be forwarded as-is to the scripts.
[INFO] $ node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile
[INFO] Starting compilation using the angular compiler.
[ERROR] (node:2000) DeprecationWarning: Chunk.modules is deprecated. Use Chunk.getNumberOfModules/mapModules/forEachModule/containsModule instead.
[INFO] Angular compilation done, starting webpack bundling.
[ERROR] Error: Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/node_modules/cuppa-ng2-slidemenu/slideMenu.ngfactory.ts:191:39: Property 'closeMenu' is private and only accessible within class 'SlideMenu'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/node_modules/cuppa-ng2-slidemenu/slideMenu.ngfactory.ts:202:39: Property 'menuToggle' is private and only accessible within class 'SlideMenu'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-program-loan-term/add-program-loan-term.component.ngfactory.ts:146:51: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-applicant-contact/create-loan-applicant-contact.component.ngfactory.ts:106:39: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-applicant-credit/create-loan-applicant-credit.component.ngfactory.ts:243:39: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-applicant-ekyc/create-loan-applicant-ekyc.component.ngfactory.ts:1021:31: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-applicant-ekyc/create-loan-applicant-ekyc.component.ngfactory.ts:1081:40: Type '"Yes"' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-applicant-ekyc/create-loan-applicant-ekyc.component.ngfactory.ts:1132:40: Type '"No"' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-applicant-ekyc/create-loan-applicant-ekyc.component.ngfactory.ts:1207:29: Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and '"Yes"'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-applicant-ekyc/create-loan-applicant-ekyc.component.ngfactory.ts:1209:29: Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and '"No"'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-applicant-cashflow/create-loan-applicant-cashflow.component.ngfactory.ts:4453:31: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-applicant-cashflow/create-loan-applicant-cashflow.component.ngfactory.ts:4600:29: Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-applicant-cashflow/create-loan-applicant-cashflow.component.ngfactory.ts:4602:29: Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-applicant-cashflow/create-loan-applicant-cashflow.component.ngfactory.ts:4604:29: Operator '==' cannot be applied to types 'string' and 'number'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/applicant-creation/applicant-creation.component.ngfactory.ts:430:39: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/applicant-creation/applicant-creation.component.ngfactory.ts:781:88: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/applicant-creation/applicant-creation.component.ngfactory.ts:811:83: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/applicant-creation/applicant-creation.component.ngfactory.ts:823:83: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/applicant-creation/applicant-creation.component.ngfactory.ts:835:83: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/applicant-creation/applicant-creation.component.ngfactory.ts:837:83: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/applicant-creation/applicant-creation.component.ngfactory.ts:849:83: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/program-policy/program-policy.component.ngfactory.ts:666:39: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/program-policy/program-policy.component.ngfactory.ts:2627:39: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/program-policy/program-policy.component.ngfactory.ts:2725:43: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/program-policy/program-policy.component.ngfactory.ts:3526:84: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/program-policy/program-policy.component.ngfactory.ts:3530:84: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/program-policy/program-policy.component.ngfactory.ts:3537:80: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/program-policy/program-policy.component.ngfactory.ts:3541:83: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/program-policy/program-policy.component.ngfactory.ts:3545:84: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/loan-creation/loan-creation.component.ngfactory.ts:213:39: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/loan-creation/loan-creation.component.ngfactory.ts:588:73: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/loan-creation/loan-creation.component.ngfactory.ts:594:71: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/list-of-loan-application/list-loan-application.component.ngfactory.ts:117:31: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-application/loan-update.component.ngfactory.ts:211:39: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-application/loan-update.component.ngfactory.ts:1038:72: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/create-loan-application/loan-update.component.ngfactory.ts:1044:70: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/list-of-consumer/list-of-consumer.component.ngfactory.ts:99:31: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/update-consumer/applicant-updation.component.ngfactory.ts:419:35: Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/update-consumer/applicant-updation.component.ngfactory.ts:765:91: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/update-consumer/applicant-updation.component.ngfactory.ts:796:81: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/update-consumer/applicant-updation.component.ngfactory.ts:818:81: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR] Error at C:/Vidyashree2016/jBPMDevelopment/los_prod_cp/LoanOriginatingSystem/target/aot/src/main/webapp/app/entities/update-consumer/applicant-updation.component.ngfactory.ts:830:81: Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.
[ERROR]     at new UserError (C:\Vidyashree2016\jBPMDevelopment\los_prod_cp\LoanOriginatingSystem\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\tsc.js:27:28)
[ERROR]     at check (C:\Vidyashree2016\jBPMDevelopment\los_prod_cp\LoanOriginatingSystem\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\tsc.js:93:15)
[ERROR]     at Tsc.typeCheck (C:\Vidyashree2016\jBPMDevelopment\los_prod_cp\LoanOriginatingSystem\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\tsc.js:173:9)
[ERROR]     at C:\Vidyashree2016\jBPMDevelopment\los_prod_cp\LoanOriginatingSystem\node_modules\@angular\tsc-wrapped\src\main.js:122:23
[ERROR]     at <anonymous>
[ERROR]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[ERROR] error Command failed with exit code 1.
[INFO] info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 09:54 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-16T12:24:00+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/183M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.2:yarn (webpack build prod) on project pods: Failed to run task: 'yarn run webpack:prod' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

My jhipster version: 4.11.1,
    yarn version: 0.18.1,
    npm vserion: 5.6.0

I also tried by upgrading jhipster to latest version but still it is not working.
Please help to resolve this.

Comment: Title is wrong, it's not about running it's about building. Dev and prod builds use different options, this is why you should start building for prod from day 1 of your project and do it regularly (continuous integration).  I think you will not get any help without sharing your code, if you can't  you should build and share a minimal project that shows the problem The version for yarn you indicated is wrong for a prod build because maven uses local versions of node and yarn specified in you pom.xml, so you could start by aligning your dev environment.